# Why do I keep getting a Certificate Verification Failures when trying to pull a github repo?

Tags: git

I am trying to pull [this git hub repo](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule.git) but whenever I execute a git clone commend it just tell me that the certificate verification failed ad then stops.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your certificate store is outdated. Try updating your system (`sudo apt update`/`sudo apt upgrade`) and the problem might go away.

It's also possible to disable certificate check in `git`, if you're sure your connection is not being tampered with:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://github.com/path/to.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it may be a [similar problem to this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51201/5538); check the output of `date` and see if it is something sane.

SSL certificates are valid from a certain point to a certain point.  Generally the "from" is when they were created, so it should be in the past.  However, if your pi believes it is, e.g., early January 1970 (which it might if `ntp` never connected, because there is no clock built in and the last day of 1969 is a default time for historical reasons), then there is probably no SSL certificate around that will validate (although some may be made to catch this possibility).